# Load R package in SPSS

Tags: r, spss

I have just started working with the integration of R into SPSS and I have problems with loading some R packages in SPSS. I can load e.g. `library(foreign)` or `library(graphics)` but it does not work for `library(xlsReadWrite)` or `library(FactoMineR)`. I have installed these packages into R already and I can load them in R also.

When using this syntax in SPSS:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM R.

library(xlsReadWrite)

END PROGRAM.
```

I am getting error `Error in library(xlsReadWrite) : there is no package called 'xlsReadWrite'`.

Many thanks,

Lakuca

Comment: Are you sure that the instance of R that SPSS is calling on is the correct one? If I remember correctly, SPSS tries to install it's own version of R that isn't necessarily the most up to date...

Comment: For SPSS 18, the plugin uses R 2.8.1. What is the output when you run: begin program r. sessionInfo(); installed.packages() end program.

Comment: ouch... R 2.8.1? wow. SPSS wants to ensure that the R experience is as bad as possible. Can the version of R that SPSS is connected to be upgraded? I have zero experience with SPSS.

Comment: I just checked, and SPSS 19 uses R 2.10. But you are bound to the R version that the plugin and corresponding R package are written for.

Answer (score 3):

In order to build the R plugin/Essentials package, SPSS Statistics has to link with a specific version of R, although you can have others installed as well.  SPSS typically releases annually, and the most current R version consistent with the SPSS Statistics release date (which means it has to be available on multiple platforms and stable several months in advance) is used.  Even if it isn't the very latest version of R, it is rare for packages not to work in older R versions.

Besides the Essentials package, there are a number of already integrated R packages - SPSS dialog boxes, syntax, and output provided by SPSS or contributed by users - that can be downloaded free from the SPSS Community at
www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral
The R Essentials are currently hosted at SPSS Developer Central at
www.spss.com/devcentral.

Regards,
Jon Peck

Comment: Thanks everybody for your hints.I have just realised that package FactoMineR was built under R version 2.5.1. Unfortunately I have just SPSS16 which requires R 2.5.0. It can probably cause troubles although FactoMineR package works when I use it in R 2.5.0

Comment: I would be very surprised if the difference between R 2.5.0 and 2.5.1 was relevant, although it certainly is possible.  I suspect that you could install R 2.5.1 and SPSS 16 would still work (but be prepared to reinstall the pieces if it doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

If you want an earlier version of xlsReadWrite you can get the sources at the [Archive page](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/src/contrib/Archive/xlsReadWrite/)